# Android: Click Button that opens AlertDialog with Number Pad

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Basically, I have a button called "Check In," and I can get it to open an AlertDialog, but not the way I want it to. I want it to open an AlertDialog that opens up an EditText, so I can input a number using the numberpad (telephone style). And then I will call a method using that value: "checkIn(value)" if they click the positivebutton (Check In), or it will do nothing if they click the negative button (Cancel).

Comment: You just need to modify and set a new layout for your AlertDialog that you are trying to achieve.  There are several examples of how to override the layouts for AlertDialogs available for review.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it work for you as below block of code, let me know if you require any changes.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder sayWindows = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);

    final EditText saySomething = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    saySomething.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    sayWindows.setPositiveButton("ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OK");
                    String mString = saySomething.getText().toString();
                    Log.i(TAG, "mString = " + mString);
                    // Your checkin() method
                }
            });

    sayWindows.setNegativeButton("cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Cancel");
                }
            });

    sayWindows.setView(saySomething);
    sayWindows.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Button btnChkIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChkIn);

btnChkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                showCheckInAlert();
            }

});

//function showing AlertDialog with EditText....
public void showCheckInAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setTitle("your title here if needed...");

        builder.setMessage("your message here if needed...");

        final EditText et = new EditText(context);

        et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);//or you can choose input type what ever you want...

        builder.setView(et);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Check In", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                checkIn(et.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

       builder.show();
    }

//function that receives EditText's value...
private void checkIn(String value)
{
   ......

   //do what ever you want to do with value string.....

   ......
}
```